# How do I programmatically suspend/resume process and its children on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to control a spawned task that in my case is a bash script that then runs another program. I wish to be able to suspend and resume those processes. My program is meant to be able to spawn any task so I cannot presume to know if the spawned process will spawn another process or processes.

I launched the process using NSTask and can control the original process but it does not affect the child processes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `SIGSTOP` signal does this. With a negative PID, the `kill` command will send it to the entire process group.

```
kill -s SIGSTOP -$pid
```

Send a `SIGCONT` to resume.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! I'm not new to Mac or other Unixes but I'm not a power user on the command line.

Comment: you can also use `%1` insread of manually typing the pid if you suspended the program with `Control`-`Z`.

Comment: ... provided it was the first job you suspended.

Comment: On MacOS 10.15.5 (Catalina) you must specify the name of the signal without the SIG prefix: `kill -s STOP $pid`

Comment: @Gabriel Actually Bash 3.2.57(1)-release on Catalina accepts either. I was guessing you actually mean that `zsh` (which is the default shell for new users starting with Catalina) requires this change, but that also doesn't seem to be the case -- it appears to work with both variations as well. So which shell exactly are you talking about? *However,* this Bash version actually complains about negative PIDs. (`zsh` seems to be fine with that.) A workaround (for better or for worse) is to use `/bin/kill` instead of the shell builtin.  The external command also accepts both `STOP` and `SIGSTOP`.

Comment: @tripleee You must be right. I was using `zsh` and it seemed to me that it did complain about SIGxxx but I didn't insist :)